# Activity does not have a parent activity name specified

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a wishlist in menu.xml. I click on wishlist menu item and the activity is opened but when click the back arrow in the top. I am getting the following error:

```
 03-25 01:13:28.278: E/NavUtils(15464): getParentActivityIntent: bad parentActivityName 'com.ylg.link.Ylg_GridViewActivity' in manifest
 03-25 01:13:28.278: D/AndroidRuntime(15464): Shutting down VM
 03-25 01:13:28.278: W/dalvikvm(15464): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417c3700)
03-25 01:13:28.286: E/AndroidRuntime(15464): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 01:13:28.286: E/AndroidRuntime(15464): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Activity Ylg_Wishlist does not have a parent activity name specified. (Did you forget to add the android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY <meta-data>  element in your manifest?)
03-25 01:13:28.286: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at android.support.v4.app.NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(NavUtils.java:178)
03-25 01:13:28.286: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at com.ylg.link.Ylg_Wishlist.onOptionsItemSelected(YLG_Wishlist.java:47)
03-25 01:13:28.286: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2566)
03-25 01:13:28.286: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$3.onClick(ActionBarView.java:171)
03-25 01:13:28.286: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
03-25 01:13:28.286: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
03-25 01:13:28.286: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-25 01:13:28.286: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-25 01:13:28.286: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 01:13:28.286: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-25 01:13:28.286: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 01:13:28.286: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-25 01:13:28.286: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-25 01:13:28.286: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-25 01:13:28.286: E/AndroidRuntime(15464):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please not that Parent_Acitivty is a fragment. And I have the below intent in the FragmentActivity

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Ylg_Wishlist.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
```

When I click on the back top button it should direct me to fragment but instead i am getting the above error.

Here is the manifest I am declaring:

```
        <activity
        android:name="com.ylg.link.Ylg_Wishlist"
        android:label="@string/wishlist"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.ylg.link.Ylg_GridViewActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Can somebody help me fix this? How do I call the back button to call the fragment rather an activity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `com.ylg.link.Ylg_GridViewActivity` is an activity and not a fragment, you can only specify Activities in the `android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY` meta data.

Also, I find it a bit odd that the name is `com.ylg.link.Ylg_GridViewActivity` in the manifest and `com.ylg.link.ylg_GridViewActivity` in the stack trace (different case for the letter 'Y' in ylg_GridViewActivity). It could also be related to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply in this case how do I open a fragment? Do I need to manually open it? In each activity that calls the navUtils?

Comment: The navutils have generally little to do with fragments. Generally you use the fragment manager to add fragments onto the back stack. see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack%28java.lang.String%29. You can also override the onBackPressed() method for the Activity to customize the back button click behaviour.